# Default enum not being added

Tags: mysql, sql

I have set up the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `acts` (
`act_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`act_name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
`short_description` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
`published` enum('1','0') DEFAULT '0',
`date_added` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`act_id`)
)
```

When I enter a new record with no value for the column `published` I expect it to auto enter a 0, but it doesn't? Why is that?

This is the query I use - `$publish` is a checkbox which has a value of 1 or nothing - is that the problem? Therefore when nothing I want it to auto add 0 but it appears I can override enum with blank?

I know I could do `if(!$publish){ $publish=0; }` but still weird behavior?

```
$query = "insert into acts ( 
                            act_name,
                            short_description,
                            published
                            ) VALUES ( 
                            '$name', 
                            '$short', 
                            '$publish'
                            )";
```

Comment: Works. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fdec/1)

Comment: @juergend Added more code to OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/415d1/1) if you leave the value from the insert statement.

This won't work

```
insert into acts (act_name, short_description, published) 
VALUES ('$name', '$short', '$publish')
```

but this will

```
insert into acts (act_name, short_description) 
VALUES ('$name', '$short')
```

So if you have no value for `published` then use a different query - the second one.

Comment: So basically, enum can be overruled, I find that odd - especially as it doesn't generate an error or warning of some sort